# How to get one item per group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I got two tables as follow:

Table 1: Fields (FieldID, FormID, Title, DateCreated, ...)

Table 2: Values (ValueID, FormID, FieldID, Value, DateModified, ...)

In some cases a field has more than one value, but in my query I just want to have one value (if it has) per Field.

Here is my code which does not work as I wish:

```
SELECT  f.FormID, f.FieldID, f.FormID, f.Title, v.Value, v.UserName FROM
(SELECT * FROM FormFields WHERE FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF') AS f
LEFT JOIN
(select FormID, ItemID, FieldID, Value, UserName, DateModified from FormValues 
    where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF') as v
ON f.FormID = v.FormID AND f.FieldID = v.FieldID
ORDER BY f.SO
```

Result:

```
FormID                                  FieldID                                 Title       Value   UserName
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    E7A78AC7-10A4-4752-85D6-A17E00C22EF9    Field One   Val One User1
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    E7A78AC7-10A4-4752-85D6-A17E00C22EF9    Field One   Val Two User2
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    8E1FAC2A-02F1-4D0D-A3E0-A184001484D8    Field Two   NULL    NULL
```

Note: Second row is unwanted.

I tried "group by" but didn't work for me. Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance,
Kardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT  f.FormID, f.FieldID, f.FormID, f.Title, v.Value, v.UserName FROM
(SELECT * FROM FormFields WHERE FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF') AS f
LEFT JOIN
(select FormID, ItemID, FieldID, Value, UserName, DateModified,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FieldID ORDER BY Value) as rn from FormValues 
    where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF') as v
ON f.FormID = v.FormID AND f.FieldID = v.FieldID AND v.rn=1
ORDER BY f.SO
```

You may need to tweak `ORDER BY Value` in `OVER` clause based on what row you want to be the first in the group (with "One" and "Two" it will return "One", but I don't know other possible values).

Comment: I'm really thankful for your kind help. Good Job! It works as I wish :)

Comment: hi again, would you take a look at this post too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264524/how-to-get-data-from-a-property-value-table-structure