# How to get data from a property-value table structure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, properties

I got 3 tables as follow:

```
Table 1: FormFields (FieldID, FormID, Title, DateModified, ...)
Table 2: ReportItems (ReportItemID, ReportID, FormID, Title, DateModified, ...)
Table 3: FormValues (ValueID, FormID, FieldID, Value, UserName, DateModified, ...)
```

For example I have selected 2 Fields of FormFields as my ReportItems. These 2 fields are a question and answer couple. Each question can have 1 answer or it could be NULL.
The key is the result should be such a html data list (dl) with 'dt's and 'dd's like this:

```
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Question1)   UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Answer1)     UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Question2)   UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Answer2)     UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Question3)   UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Answer3)     UserName

Question 1
    Answer 1
Question 2

Question 3
    Answer 3
Question 4

Question 5
    Answer 5
```

I used a query like this, but it doesn't return the result I wish:

```
select rf.FormID, rf.FieldID, rf.ReportItemTitle, v.Value from 
    (select r.ReportItemID, r.FormID, r.FieldID, r.Title as ReportItemTitle from 
        (select ReportItemID, ReportID, FormID, FieldID, Title 
            from ReportItems 
            where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF' and ShowInList = 0) r
    JOIN
        (select FormID, FieldID, Title 
            from FormFields 
            where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF') f
        ON r.FormID = f.FormID AND r.FieldID = f.FieldID) rf
LEFT JOIN
    (select FormID, FieldID, Value
        from FormValues 
        where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF' and UserName = '0000000000') v
ON rf.FormID = v.FormID AND rf.FieldID = v.FieldID

FormID                                  FieldID                                 ReportItem's Title  Values
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    E7A78AC7-10A4-4752-85D6-A17E00C22EF9    Question's Title    user's 1st question goes here...
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    E7A78AC7-10A4-4752-85D6-A17E00C22EF9    Question's Title    user's 2nd question goes here...
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    E7A78AC7-10A4-4752-85D6-A17E00C22EF9    Question's Title    user's 2nd question goes here...
2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF    8E1FAC2A-02F1-4D0D-A3E0-A184001484D8    Answer's Title  admin's answer to user's 1st question
```

Note:

- Empty answers are the one has not been answered (NULL).
- The result should be based upon **UserName** and **ReportID**
- All IDs are GUID
- Both questions and answers are stored in FormValues table

Maybe I should use cursor, but I'm really confused what to do. I'd highly appreciate if someone help me.

Many thanks in advance,

Kardo

Comment: Please provide data/structure script for these table. This will make more understandable.

Comment: @RonakVyas: hi, I just simplified my question and put it down here as answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think i know what you mean

```
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Question1)   UserName
ReportID    FormID  FieldID Value (Answer1)     UserName
```

do you want questions and answers in the same selection column? you need to order by reportID, FormID, FieldID and let the presentation logic keep track of the current ids to display it in a nested way like (or you need an orm-tool to make the mapping for you and user an object model)

```
 <ul>
    <li>report1
        <ul>
           <li>form1
               <ul>
                  <li> question1
                      <ul>
                          <li>answer 1 by user 1</li>
                          <li>answer 2 by user 2</li>
```

....

Comment: yes, something like that. In fact I want to show a series of questions and answers, by reportid, related to an specific user. something like a conversation between a user and an admin, for each user's question, there should be an answer from admin, if not answered yet, just a place holder. the key is, the sequence of questions and answers, order by date, should be held. Imagine a sequence of blocks like this: (Q1-[A1]) (Q2-[A2]) (Q3-[A3])...

Comment: i find your second answer a bit more confusing than the first sql, what i don't get there is why you always select from temp-tables like this one here:

"(select r.ReportItemID, r.FormID, r.FieldID, r.Title as ReportItemTitle from 
        (select ReportItemID, ReportID, FormID, FieldID, Title 
            from ReportItems 
            where FormID = '2D6C42E1-0C95-4E40-B792-A17E00C001BF' and ShowInList = 0) r"

couldn't you just select and join with the original table in all these cases?